# Connecting to a different MySQL server through Sails JS

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have a use case where I need to fetch data from two different DBs placed on  different server(one of them being my own localhost/dev/prod). On providing details for connection using **adapter : 'sails-mysql**', whenever i try & access the DB(for a simple select query), it throws this exception:

```
    debug: err, response --  Error: Could not connect to MySQL:
    Error: Handshake inactivity timeout
    at afterwards (/Users/xx/code/xx/xx/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/connections/spawn.js:72:13)
    at /Users/xx/code/xx/xx/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/connections/spawn.js:40:7
    at Handshake.onConnect [as _callback] (/Users/xx/code/xx/xx/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:54:9)
    at Handshake.Sequence.end (/Users/xx/code/xx/xx/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:96:24)
    at /Users/xx/code/xx/xx/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:399:18
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/xx/code/xx/xx/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:398:13
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:112:11) undefined
```

Example of `connections.js`:

```
MySQLServerForDataServer: {
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    host: (process.env.DBNAME_DATA_SERVER_HOST),
    user: (process.env.DBNAME_DATA_SERVER_USER),
    password: (process.env.DBNAME_DATA_SERVER_PWD),
    database: (process.env.DBNAME_DATA_SERVER_DB)
}
```

I'm able to access this server through Valentina Studio or whatever(ssh key is added on there server too), but through code, it's not letting me through.

Can anyone suggest something which might help me connect to this DB Server?

Comment: Can you add an example of your connections.js?

Comment: MySQLServerForDataServer : {
    adapter : 'sails-mysql',
    host: (process.env.DBNAME_DATA_SERVER_HOST),
    user: (process.env.DBNAME_DATA_SERVER_USER),
    password: (process.env.DBNAME_DATA_SERVER_PWD),
    database: (process.env.DBNAME_DATA_SERVER_DB) 
}

Comment: can you try by adding to your `connections.js` the key/value `port : 3306` ? Also which version of node.js and sails.js are you using?

Comment: Have you tried the actual db connection data in the `connections.js` to test if that works?

Comment: @LS_ --> Yes, i tried mapping it to the port 3306 as well. No Luck.

Comment: @johnabrams7 -> Yep, instead of saving these connection values in .env, i also tried using them directly but couldn't get through still.. :(

Comment: I also tried connecting to this server through me localhost/dev/prod terminal.
mysql -h xx.xxx.xx.xx. -u <username> -p 
also tried connecting through the private IP.. but it gives me the same error.

Comment: @LS_ -> I'm using sails 0.12, node - 9.8.0

Comment: Try running an adapter test with the database URL using:
`WATERLINE_ADAPTER_TESTS_URL=mysql://root:password@localhost/adapter_tests npm test`

Comment: @Sandy - Ah, Sails 0.12. What version of the sails-mysql adapter are you using? sails-mysql v0.11.5 is for Sails v0.12 but the latest sails-mysql 1.0.0 is for Sails v1.0+.